# Return a value for use in different class

Tags: java, jpanel, actionlistener

I have the class BossInfo which extends JPanel and has a few components like JLabel, JTextField. My main method is in another file ("DamageCalculator").
Basically, a value is entered into a JTextField via an action listener and I'd like to pass that value to a different file (to use it in calculations). I'm having a lot of trouble with the logic. Here is my class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BossInfo extends JPanel {

    private JLabel      bossLabel, resultLabel;
    private JTextField  bossHp;
    String bossHpText = new String("");
    int valRecd = 0;

    public BossInfo() {
        //Labels
        bossLabel = new JLabel("Boss HP: (Hit Enter to set)");
        resultLabel = new JLabel("---");
        //Text field for user input of boss hp
        bossHp = new JTextField(15);
        bossHp.addActionListener(new TempListener());

        //add components
        add(bossLabel);
        add(bossHp);
        add(resultLabel);

    } //end BossInfo object 

    public void setVal(int valRecd) {
        this.valRecd = valRecd;
    }

    private class TempListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {            
            int hp;
            bossHpText = bossHp.getText();
            hp = Integer.valueOf(bossHpText);
            dc.setVal(hp);
            resultLabel.setText(bossHpText);
        }//end action performed
    }//end TempListener
} //end class BossInfo
```

How can I use bossHpText in another class? The "actionPerformed" gets mad if it's any return type other than void so I'm not sure it's meant to return anything.

EDIT: Code updated based on suggestions.

Comment: You can have a public variable in the other class that gets changed by actionPerformed()

Comment: Ahh, interesting. So, say I just want to print the value of bossHpText from the main method:

    public class DamageCalculator extends Frame
    {
            String result = new String();

     public static void main(String[] args) {
                result = actionPerformed();
                System.out.print(result);
        }
    }


Ugh, sorry didn't realize the formatting is different for comments.

Answer (score 1):

Have a variable `valRecd` in the `MainClass`.

On your `actionPerformed`, call the setter method for this `valRecd`, e.g,

```
MainClass obj = new MainClass();   //in your constructor.

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int hp;
        bossHpText = bossHp.getText();
        hp = Integer.parseInt(text);
        obj.setVal(hp);                   //add this line.
        resultLabel.setText(bossHpText);
}
```

where `setVal` might be something like this:

```
public void setVal(int valRecd) {
    this.valRecd = valRecd;
}
```

Comment: When you say MainClass, would that be the class with my main method?
Also, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Yes. The class with the main method where you do the calculations.

Comment: Ahh okay. So the setVal method goes in the BossInfo class because that is where it is defined. I added the changes suggested in the actionPerformed method. Which class does the "MainClass" constructor go in? So I'm understanding correctly, we are creating a variable in the main class. Then, in the BossInfo class we are changing the value of that variable?

Comment: So, I updated the code above to reflect the current code. My main class is name "DamageCalculator". In the DamageCalculator class I have defined:               
    int valRecd = 0;              
Should that be defined within the Main method? Currently it is outside the main method.

Comment: Your setter method should be in Damagecalculator. Define it as a private variable and use the setter to assign the value

Comment: Thanks @anindya-dutta ! I am now able to return that value to the other class. Now, when I try to set a JLabel with that value, nothing is happening. Here is the method that I create (per your advice):  
public void setBossHp (String value) {
  bossHp = value;
  bossHpLabel.setText(value);
  //System.out.print(value);
 }

Comment: I have the System.out.print just so I can test that the value is returned. However, the label "bossHpLabel" is never updated with the new value. Any ideas why the label does not change? Thank you!

Comment: You mean value has the correct string and yet Label is not setting that string?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I put "bossHpLabel.setText(value);" in the "setBossHp" method. I figured when the method was called (from the 'BossInfo' class), it would set/update the value in bossHpLabel.